# Karate not able to use set multiple with nested json array

Tags: karate

I am using karate 0.9.4 and I have been trying to set json payload which has a nested array in it.
For example I am trying to this :

```
* set foo

      | path   | value   |
      | bar    | 'baz'   |
      | a[0].b | 'ban'   |
      | a[0].c | 'abc'   |
      | a[1].b | 'def'   |
```

However, the result is

```
{
  "bar": "baz",
  "a": [
    {
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify it for now please:

```
* set foo
  | path   | value   |
  | bar    | 'baz'   |
  | a[0]   | { a: 'ban', c: 'abc' } |
  | a[1]   | { b: 'def' }           |
```